# iPhone 7 NSUserDefaults turning into nil

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, nsuserdefaults

I have an iPhone 7 , and I also use it for development. I noticed that in my app , I was storing a session token for auto login purposes into the NSUserDefaults. But sometimes , without removing it the session token was nil and the auto login is not working. This also happens to other apps , where some times it asks me to login again , although I already have. I am guessing that somehow to NSUserDefaults that most of the apps use are being erased somehow. Anyone having a similar issue ?

```
class func setSessionToken(_ token: String){
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        defaults.setValue(token, forKey: sessionTokenKey)
        defaults.synchronize()
    }

class func getSessionToken()->String?{
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        return defaults.string(forKey: sessionTokenKey)
    }
```

Comment: Could you put a `print()` statement before the `defaults.setValue(token, forKey: sessionTokenKey)` line and print out the `token` for me? Also, you should `COMMAND+SHIFT+F` and paste "forKey: sessionTokenKey" in the search field to ensure that you are not removing the value anywhere else in your project.

Comment: Note that calling [UserDefaults.synchronize()](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/userdefaults/1414005-synchronize) is no longer necessary as of iOS 8. "Because this method is automatically invoked at periodic intervals, use this method only if you cannot wait for the automatic synchronization (for example, if your application is about to exit) ..."

Answer (score 0):

This issue  normally occurs when Running an iOS8 or 9 simulator followed by an iOS10 simulator and  NSUserDefaults  stop working in the simulator.

But, in your case if it is not working in iPhone also . You can try it with latest version of Xcode8 .

Comment: Why on earth would someone use Xcode 8 beta 2 if Xcode 8.2.1 official has been released for over a month already?

Comment: yea , you are right . I have gone through this link https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/143155#143155